# In the context of Autofac: What is the difference between a Service and a Component?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

What exactly is the difference between a `Service` and a `Component`? And how does the extension method `RegisterComponent()` relate to this definitions?

Autofac's glossary defines it as follows:

**Component**

> A body of code that declares the Services it provides and the
>   Dependencies it consumes

**Service**

> A well-defined behavioural contract shared between a providing and a
>   consuming Component

This confuses me.. Would it be correct to say, that a component *uses* several services? Something like the example below?

```
public interface IServiceA
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do some magic 
    }
}

public class ComponentA
{
    private readonly IServiceA serviceA;

    public ComponentA(IServiceA serviceA)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
    }

    public void SomeOperation()
    {
        this.serviceA.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Or is a component always an implementation of a service/interface? I just don't get it.

I would be thankful if somebody could clarify with a catchable example.

Comment: This is a bit a simplification, but you can replace the word "Component" with "class" or "implementation", and replace the word "Service" with "interface" or "abstraction."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Component` is something that will be concrete piece of code after the resolution process.

A `Component` is described by one or multiple service. ie : `Component` is `ServiceA`

A `Service` is used to describe a `Component` and will be used to define relation between component. ie : `ComponentA` needs `serviceB` and `serviceC`.

In the following code

```
builder.RegisterType<XXX>()
       .As<IA>()
       .Named<IB>("X");
```

`XXX` would be the `Component` described by a typed service and a named service.

Comment: Thx for replying. So in my example from above a `component` is an implementation of `IServiceA` and the interface itself is the (describing) service?

Comment: In your case you can think of Component and Service like class and interface

Comment: For reference, [this is documented](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html) and there is [a glossary](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary.html).